# Default right-click context menu in WPF GridView

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm currently working on a project that uses the WPF GridView. I've been charged with altering the right-click context menu.

Currently the right-click context menu brings up a menu with a checklist of the columns in it. Is this default behaviour? I'm unable to find any such context menu in the code. I need to somehow persist these column selections so they survive a restart of the application.

I hope someone can help. I've not been able to find any information on this menu anywhere!

Mark

Comment: the context menu is probably defined in he XAML did you go over it?

Comment: I did yes, several times. I've spent a good portion of the day looking at the XAML trying to work it out! I'm new to WPF, see.

Comment: Post the grid view Xaml it probably will help

Answer (score 0):

That's not default behaviour and would have had to be coded.

Comment: Ok I'll have another look but I'm sure I've looked and searched everywhere!

Answer (score 0):

Not only is there no default context menu built into a WPF `GridView`, but I don't think that you can even attach one at all. The `GridView` *may* be hosted in a `ListView` control and that could have its own context menu.

If you can find the XAML file that contains the `GridView`, then look or search for the keyword `ContextMenu`. This is the name of the property which gets context menus attached.

Alternatively, search through the whole solution for any bits of text that is displayed either in the context menu, or maybe even in the `GridView` headers.

The best advice that I can give is to get a good book and start learning WPF.